# Laravel 9 - Set default model attribute to auth user id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I want to pass current user's id into a column by default. I tried giving it in the migration but didn't work, this code did work when I pass an integer but it gives an error when I try to set it to Auth::id()

Code I've tried (in the model file)

```
    protected $attributes = [
        'employee_id' => Auth::id(),
    ];
```

Error I get :

```
Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

It does work when I give it a hard coded string or integer value. But I need to give it the current user's id.

Comment: set it when saving the record, listen for the creating event that gets fired

Comment: That's the problem actually. This is a pretty large project and I don't know all the places that inserts a record into this table to add that attribute manually. That's why I'm trying to solve it at the source (model or migration). Also I'm pretty new to laravel and I don't know how to listen for an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's really a good idea, but you can add this in your Model

```
protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->employee_id = Auth::id();
        });
    }
```

Check the docs for the complete list of event.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

Comment: I just came back to write this solution! Someone recommended me the code below and it worked like a charm. BTW, why don't you think it's a good idea? I mean it gets the job done and it's exactly what I need.

static::creating(fn($model) => $model->employee_id = auth()->id());

Comment: I set this as the best answer but there's a typo, I think you should change "=>" to "=", to avoid confusion for other people that might google this solution.

Comment: I've made the correction in the code. You said it's a pretty large project and you don't know the code very well. I can't guarante that will not break something somewhere since you might override some existing code by doing so. It could also be a pain to debug if you forgot that your model have that kind of method implemented.
That being said, it's possible that everything will work as you want and you'll have no problem, it's just a warning :)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks so much! I don't think there'll be any override issues because I just added the column to the table so it wasn't used anywhere else before.